# Why Cucumber repeats Java/Selenium exception text?

Tags: java, cucumber

### For example, tried to locale a web page element by ID and it was not there - why  Cucumber repeats the Java output (in addition to - expected - its own scenario/feature/steps failure text) and can I prevent that?

```
    Testing started at 4:51 PM ...
    Nov 28, 2018 4:51:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
    ================== Beginning ===================================
    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
    >>>ERROR. There is no Translation status column

    For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
    Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
    System info: host: 'T1650', ip: '10.68.1.61', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
      at pageObjects.VerificationPage.findStatusIcon(VerificationPage.java:40)
      at stepDefinitions.VerificationPageSteps.user_verifies_translation_status(VerificationPageSteps.java:24)
      at *.Then BitBucket user verifies Translation Status(C:/Verification/src/test/resources/features/Verification_Test.feature:11)
    ******************** Ending ***********************************
    Failed scenarios:
    c:/Verification/src/test/resources/features/Verification_Test.feature:8 # Scenario: User checks a repository

    1 Scenarios (1 failed)
    3 Steps (1 failed, 2 passed)
    0m20.931s

    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 

    >>>ERROR. There is no Translation status column

    For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
    Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
    System info: host: 'T1650', ip: '10.68.1.61', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
      at pageObjects.VerificationPage.findStatusIcon(VerificationPage.java:40)
      at stepDefinitions.VerificationPageSteps.user_verifies_translation_status(VerificationPageSteps.java:24)
      at *.Then BitBucket user verifies Translation Status(C:/Verification/src/test/resources/features/Verification_Test.feature:11)

    Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

    Process finished with exit code 1/
```

---

step definition (looks for a special column in Branches page of Bitbucket (stash)):

```
public class TranslationVerificationPageSteps {
    private TestContext testContext;
    private TranslationVerificationPage translationVerificationPage;

    public TranslationVerificationPageSteps(TestContext context) {
        testContext = context;
        translationVerificationPage = testContext.getPageObjectManager().getTranslationVerificationPage();
    }

    @Then("^BitBucket user verifies Translation Status$")
    public void user_verifies_translation_status(){
        translationVerificationPage.findTranslationStatusIcon();
    }
}
```

Implementation (just to show that I tried other ways - the majority of those commented out variants also produce that effect - Java/Selenium exception text is shown twice - or Java error text is not shown at all):

```
try {
            translationColumn = driver.findElement(By.id("translation-status-branch-list-col"));
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {

            throw new NoSuchElementException("\n\n>>>ERROR. There is no Translation status column\n");


    // variant 2
    //Assert.fail("\n\n>>>ERROR. Test failed: no Translation status column\n\n");

// variant 3
  // throw new AssertionError("\n\n>>>ERROR. Test failed: no Translation status column\n\n");

  }

// variant 4
//            try {
//                Assert.assertNotNull(translationColumn);
//
//            } catch (AssertionError foo) {
//                System.out.println("\n\nTest failed: no Translation status column\n\n");
//                //e.printStackTrace();
//                //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
//
//            }
```

Comment: Please add step definition code

Comment: Added step definition to my question above

Comment: There is no point in trapping an exception to just rethrow it, since you are changing the exception message, if you catch it then wrap it in a new custom exception, otherwise ignore it and let your test framework, cucumber in this case report it.

Comment: I did rethrow because catch (NoSuchElementException e) did not cause (expected) abrupted failure of my test

Answer (score 1):

I did some debugging and it looks like I can answer my own question - though, IMHO, it's a **bug** in Cucumber:

1) First, it's **Java**/Selenium failure text - it's the text (given in Question's "code" part) between
================== Beginning ===
and 
 ================== Ending =

2) Now, **Cucumber** starts to process the failure and prints out the information -

in **this.printSummary()** method (Runtime.class):

a) prints out failed Step/Feature information - which is good and expected

b) prints out - **again** :-( - same Java/Selenium failure text that has been already printed.

```
public void run() throws IOException {
        List features = this.runtimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(this.resourceLoader);
        Formatter formatter = this.runtimeOptions.formatter(this.classLoader);
        Reporter reporter = this.runtimeOptions.reporter(this.classLoader);
        StepDefinitionReporter stepDefinitionReporter = this.runtimeOptions.stepDefinitionReporter(this.classLoader);
        this.glue.reportStepDefinitions(stepDefinitionReporter);
        Iterator var5 = features.iterator();

        while(var5.hasNext()) {
            CucumberFeature cucumberFeature = (CucumberFeature)var5.next();
            cucumberFeature.run(formatter, reporter, this);
        }

        formatter.done();
        formatter.close();

        this.printSummary();
    }
```